# Show encoded url on web browser address bar

Tags: java, jsp, network-programming, cryptography

i want to show encoded url on my web browser address bar when corresponding url is going.
i aleady get url and encoded by using given code.

```
       String getURL=request.getRequestURL().toString();
       out.println(getURL);
       String output = URLEncoder.encode(getURL);
       out.println(output);
```

Comment: Why did you add the `cryptography` tag, your question ist just about encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode only the individual query string parameter name and/or value.

```
String url = "http://mysite.com/query?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("bla bla", "ISO-8859-1"); // Or "UTF-8".
```